# intel-oneApi CUDA support was not enabled at compilation time

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, intel-oneapi

I am new to `intel-oneapi`, I followed [intel's instructions](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-repo-instructions.html) to install oneApi on Ubuntu 20.04.

I successfully compiled `vector-add` example. Unfortunately, during runtime I get the following exception:

```
pi_die: CUDA support was not enabled at compilation time
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I need special flags to run it on nvidia GPU? when I switch `sycl::default_selector` to `sycl::cpu_selector` then code is executed without exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targetting Nvidia hardware using DPC++ you currently need to re-compile DPC++ with this support.
The instructions for doing this are in [the repository here](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#build-dpc-toolchain-with-support-for-nvidia-cuda).

Once you have done that you can use the appropriate device selector to choose the Nvidia GPU for executing.